Dropdown value is being obscured after being selected
Writing code to simulate user input. The website has a few dropdown list with a bunch of values and user needs to select either one of them. Everything else runs fine except. it can login and it can go to the form filling out part. It selects a value from one of the dropdown and it moves on to the next one and it stops and the first dropdown obscures itself.
// Function to select the first option from a dropdown
def selectFirstOptionFromDropdown(Object dropdownObject) {
    WebUI.click(dropdownObject)
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    List<WebElement> options = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/ul/li")))
    //WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div")))
    //element.click()
    options.get(1).click()
}
// Function to submit Annex A form
def submitAnnexA() {

    // Select the first option from the dropdown lists
    selectFirstOptionFromDropdown(findTestObject('Object Repository/annexA_han/Page_Annex A/div_Please SelectPlease SelectOutpatient De_b7f71f'))
    selectFirstOptionFromDropdown(findTestObject('Object Repository/annexA_han/Page_Annex A/span_Please Select'))
    selectFirstOptionFromDropdown(findTestObject('Object Repository/annexA_han/Page_Annex A/div_Please SelectPlease SelectAnaesthesiolo_d69f76'))
    selectFirstOptionFromDropdown(findTestObject('Object Repository/annexA_han/Page_Annex A/div_Please SelectPlease SelectAE (Observati_e9e2b1'))
}

The actual result:

Error:
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <li class="option selected"> is not clickable at point (900,646) because another element <div class="nice-select lhServiceClass"> obscures it

Tried using different XPath selector and it still does not work and the obscuring persists. Can't figure out why it's happening.
When inspecting elements:


Reason:
'org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element  is not clickable at point (900,646) because another element  obscures it' the error message that I got.

Prefer [edit] than post a comment
